# PHP warning magic method set() class.XMLHttpRequest.php

Tags: php, warnings, magic-methods

i have a php script that runs perfectly
but i get 2 errors:

```
    Warning: The magic method __set() must have public visibility
 and cannot be static in C:\wamp\www\class.XMLHttpRequest.php on line 63

    Warning: The magic method __get() must have public visibility
 and cannot be static in C:\wamp\www\class.XMLHttpRequest.php on line 89
```

is this important? can i make it dissapear? or fix ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need to show the PHP file in question.

Comment: please post the functions `__set()` and `__get()` on lines 63 and 89...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post the corresponding code.

You can fix the issue by removing the keyword `static` and replace `private` with `public` on the lines 63 and 89. But even if a private static `__set()` or `__get()` method is invalid PHP and doesn't make much sense, maybe the guy who wrote the code had a reason to do so. Check nearby comments for hints.

Comment: line 63 : private function __set($property, $value), line 89 : private function __get($property)

Comment: youre right removing the "private" from both resolves the thing, thanks !

Comment: Oh, didn't catch the public visibility problem. If the programmer made the method private, he probably didn't want external code to be able to access the class.

Answer (score 1):

> line 63 : private function __set($property, $value), line 89 : private function __get($property)

The source of the error may lie in the code that are calling these functions. How many parts of the website call `__set` and `__get`? (perform a file recursive search for this)

I would say it might be risky to suddenly change a private to public without seeing overall what that affects first. MVCs can be tricky to figure out.